# Why does PropertyChangedCallback method not execute from Dependency Property OverrideMetadata?

Tags: wpf, metadata, dependency-properties

I have a class called CustomGrid which derives from the Grid class. I am attempting to run a method when there are changes made to the grid's parent window's title by using OverrideMetadata on the Window class's TitleProperty. My approach to this problem, however, does not seem to work despite having another PropertyChangedCallback method I implemented, that works, using the same approach (OverrideMetadata) for the grid's MarginProperty:

```
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    static CustomGrid()
    {
        Type ownerType = typeof(CustomGrid);
        MarginProperty.OverrideMetadata(ownerType, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMarginPropertyChanged)));

        Window.TitleProperty.OverrideMetadata(ownerType, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTitlePropertyChanged)));
    }

    private static void OnMarginPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This executes when the grid's margin changes.
    }

    private static void OnTitlePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This does not execute when the parent window's title changes.
    }
}
```

Why does the OnTitlePropertyChanged method not execute when the grid's parent window's title is changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback method is not called because you did not set the `Window.Title` property on a `CustomGrid` instance.

The expression

```
Window.TitleProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(CustomGrid),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnTitlePropertyChanged));
```

registers the `OnTitlePropertyChanged` callback for the type `CustomGrid`. This means the callback is called whenever the dependency property is set on instances of `CustomGrid`, but only on those instances, not any objects like e.g. the MainWindow.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now. Thank you for the clarification on that. How would I still approach detecting when the title is changed though?

Comment: By a Binding perhaps.

Comment: If I bind directly to the window's title property using `SetBinding(Window.TitleProperty, myBinding)` do I have to add this property to my class using `AddOwner` or is that binding good enough on its own with the `Window.TitleProperty.OverrideMetadata` in the constructor?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It makes no sense to override the Title property metadata for a class that is not derived from Window.

Comment: If I do a binding as you suggested, I need to bind to a dependency property. How else could I detect the changes in the parent window's title property then?

Comment: Sure, you would have to declare a [custom dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/custom-dependency-properties?view=netdesktop-6.0)